# Remote profilling from VS2022 on Azure WebApp?

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2022

I wanted to start remote profiling in my Azure WebApp as described in this article from 2015: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/remote-profiling-support-in-azure-app-service/

[image: Profiling in Visual Studio]

But the functionality no longer exists because [Cloud Explorer in Visual Studio 2022 no longer exists](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/azure/vs-azure-tools-resources-managing-with-cloud-explorer?view=vs-2022). The page says this:

> If you don’t use the publishing feature, the Connected Services node inside each Project in your Solution can help you configure access to Azure resources and invoke various operations like remote debugging, **remote profiling**, starting/stopping the application, view streaming logs, and more.

So I tried looking into the Connected Services tab, I added my WebApp in there but there is no remote profiling option.

[image: Trying to find remote profiling in VS 2022]

Does anyone know how can I run remote profiling for Azure WebApp from VS 2022?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to deploy an Asp.net web app to azure app service from Visual Studio and published to Azure app service successfully by creating a new App service plan and added that Azure App Service using the connected services option in VS.

I can be able to see the start profiling, stop profiling along with other options as shown in the below screenshot:

[image]

But when I tried to access the `Azure App Service` which is created in the azure portal using the `connected services` in VS, it's not showing the options to `start/stop` the `remote profiling` as shown in the below image because of webapp is not hosted in that particular Azure App service using the publish option from Visual Studio.

[image]

We can `start/stop` profiling when our web app is published in the `Azure App Service` which is Published from Visual Studio.